# Hash sign in jQuery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

Being a pragmatic coder I tend to miss some obvious things and I wonder,
What's the difference between

```
$('loc')
$('#loc')
```

The more info the better about the ins and outs of #

Comment: It's all in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`$('loc')` is an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), looking for `<loc>` elements.

`$('#loc')` is an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), looking for `id="loc"` elements.

Think CSS when looking at almost all [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), they're *very* close if not identical in most cases.

Comment: That's such a simple and great answer. Thank you