# When calling jQuery's .trigger() function propagation to other handlers bound to the element stops

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-autocomplete-light

When using .trigger() event on element other events bound to this event are not firing. When I comment this line everything goes well. I'm using django-autocomplete-light library so I simplified this example.

```
<input type="text" class="js-input">
<div class="js-box">
    <!-- code inside the box is loaded dynamically -->
    <a href="#" class="js-autocomplete-item"></a>
</div>
```

**Not working**

selectChoice event is fired and.

```
var boxClickHandler = function(e) {
    var current = this.box.find('.' + this.hilightClass);

    $(".js-input").trigger('selectChoice', [current, this]);
};

$(".js-box").on("mouseclick", ".js-autocomplete-item", $.proxy(boxClickHandler, this));

// somewhere else in the code
$(".js-input").bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
    // empty handler
});

// somewhere else in the code
$(document).on("click", ".js-autocomplete-item", function(e){
    // FIXME: this code is not running
});
```

**Working**

```
var boxClickHandler = function(e) {
    var current = this.box.find('.' + this.hilightClass);

    // $(".js-input").trigger('selectChoice', [current, this]);
};

$(".js-box").on("mouseclick", ".js-autocomplete-item", $.proxy(boxClickHandler, this));

// somewhere else in the code
$(".js-input").bind('selectChoice', function(e, choice, autocomplete) {
    // empty handler
});

// somewhere else in the code
$(document).on("click", ".js-autocomplete-item", function(e){
    // when selectChoice event is not triggered from boxClickHandler this code is running
});
```

I am a bit confused. I tried many approaches and I believe this is something simple, because this code was running a while ago (before I made an upgrade of django-autocomplete-light lib which uses this code and lots of others in order to run Django 1.8). But it seems like it is just something to do with jQuery. Has anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried opening the "developer tools" or your browser's equivalent to see if any errors are getting triggered by this statement:

```
$(".js-input").trigger('selectChoice', [current, this]);
```

Without a try/catch - any error/exception stops the execution of all following javascript.

Perhaps try logging this object and/or its properties:

```
var inputElement = $(".js-input");
```

Comment: No errors and objects are correct. I was debugging this problem for quite a while - selectionChoice handler works properly though and just to make a point I removed everything from it so no possible error/dom manipulation etc. could occur.

Comment: You might be better off to give your html elements id's and reference them by id instead.

This page illustrates how:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368582/hash-sign-in-jquery-calls

So in your case - give your input element an id and then reference that id in your jquery call (with the hash/number-sign prefix).

Otherwise try my other suggestion and log the element you're trying to reference:
console.log('input:', $(".js-input"));

or iterate and log its properties.

Comment: I got it. I was clearing box elements after click was made (there was another bind to this event). It was that simple as you say. I think it would be helpful for others to say explicitly in your answer that it can't be the case that propagation to other handlers would stop. Thanks!